# Time Machine disk is filling up to quickly

Tags: time-machine, time

Every time Time Machine does a backup of my Yosemite working disk (140 GB), it adds about 20 GB to the size of the contents of my backup disk, and it fills up very quickly. This happens even during the night when both I and my computer are sleeping. I don't think it should work this way!

Comment: Do you have a virtual machine running? Or another very large file changing continuously?

Comment: you might backup some enormous files you are not aware of. Use http://grandperspectiv.sourceforge.net to check the contents of your Mac. Exclude directories from TS backup in the TimeMachine settings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a program like BackupLoupe to browse the changes added in each backup version.

Otherwise, the [tmutil](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/tmutil.8.html) command (specifically `tmutil compare`) can be used to observe the differences between two TimeMachine backups (or a backup and the current state).

Comment: BackupLoupe found the answer: Google was maintaining a 20GB Library in my machine. Getting rid of gMail solved it.  Thanks!!! (Is this how google buildes its Cloud?!)

Comment: I have seem that Chrome has options for caching offline Gmail and Google Drive. BTW, if you like my answer, please accept it.